# Can I have two UISearchBar in one ViewController?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Can I have two `UISearchbar` in one `ViewController` ?

Basically I have a map view and I want to put a source and destination `UISearchBar` on top.

Now if I add two UIISearchBar and thus two `UISearchDisplayControllers`, how do I determine which search bar it is in use in the delegate functions ?

I was planning to use just one `UISearchBar` which will take source first and then destination, but now the plan is to show 2 search bars.

I got everything working with one search bar.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store both UISearchBars in an IBOutlet like

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISearchBar *firstSearchBar;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISearchBar *secondSearchBar;
```

Then in your delegates do

```
- (void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if (searchBar == self.firstSearchBar) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

This approach can also be used when you have to deal with more than one UIAlertView, UITableView, UICollectionView etc.

Comment: I approve this, except you should always use `isEqual` when comparing objects.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo No, not really.. who told you that?

Answer (score 0):

i think i figured it out... i have to create properties of the uisearchdisplaycontrollers and then i can refer the searchtableview etc to figure out the uisearchbar in use